# Why can't I set innerHTML on selector?

Tags: jquery, dom

On a page with this:

```
<div id="myMessage">Text to change</div>
```

The following will successfully change the displayed text:

```
document.getElementById("myMessage").innerHTML = "New text!";
```

but using the `div`'s selector does not:

```
$("myMessage").innerHTML = "This text will not appear!";
```

Why?

Comment: `$()` returns an array-like object which doesn't have an `.innerHTML` property. You need to also fix your selector. `$('#myMessage')[0].innerHTML = "..."`. However, you can avoid this and use `.html()`: `$('#myMessage').html("Whatever you want");`. That would be the jQuery way.

Comment: Your selector is wrong - and you could use the jquery function for this as well - i.e. `$("#myMessage").html("my msg");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the ID selector in the Sizzle query. But then, you're trying to access a DOM property of a jQuery object, which will not work.

You should use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
$("#myMessage").text( "This text will not appear!" );
```

If you wish to use `.innerHTML`, you can use `get()`, but then that seems pointless since you may as well use `document.getElementById()`...

```
$('#myMessage').get(0).innerHTML = 'This text will not appear!';
// or
$('#myMessage')[0].innerHTML = 'This text will not appear!';
```

Finally, you could also use `prop()` as follows:

```
$('#myMessage').prop('innerHTML', 'This text will not appear!');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#myMessage").html("This text will appear!");
```

Comment: "Please upvote the answers that have already been posted" ... what? only useful/good quality answers should be upvoted. **None of these are useful.**

Comment: @KevinB Yes, of which there are several already in this question... Can you please tell me how the answer I've posted 'isn't useful'?

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can just use `.html()`. Your selector is also missing the `#` for ID.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#myMessage").html("This text will not appear!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myMessage">Text to change</div>
```